# Enum description in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, enums

I have a Enum with Key and description like below. In JSP I will be getting the value and I want to display the description.

```
public enum STATUS {
    ACTIVE("A", "Active"),
    INACTIVE("I","Inactive"),
    PENDING("PND","Pending");

private final String value;
    private final String description;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    STATUS(String value, String description) {
        this.value=value;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public static STATUS fromValue(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            for (STATUS status : values()) {
                if (status.value.equals(value)) {
                    return status;
                }
            }
        }
        return getDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Define precisely "*How to proceed with this?*"

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "getting the value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've there a valid Javabean-compliant getter method, you can just access it the usual Javabean way.

```
${status.description}
```

Or if it's referenced as a property of *another* javabean, then do so

```
${order.status.description}
```

Comment: I will get the value as "A" from other object (Aobj) and STATUS enum is other object, I don't have any reference of STATUS  in the object (Aobj).

Comment: Why do you have a `String` `"A"` instead of `Status` `ACTIVE` in your `Aobj`? You've got some design mistakes there. Just replace that `String` by `Status` and this problem will disappear and everything else will instantly become so much easier.

Comment: I surely agree, after you said it is design issue, then I corrected myself and could able to get the description.